# Sharepoint Online HTML Editor not working

Tags: sharepoint-online, html

Any one else is facing the same problem?
I also attached screenshot for more clarity.
any suggestions?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was from Microsoft side.
It was working fine after some time.

So, don't worry if you face this type of issue.